# Limiting my website embed to only a handful of domains

Tags: html, iframe, embed

I have an web app that I want to embed on different websites. However, I don't want the embed to be available to all the domains. So lets say http://mysite1.com, and http://mysite2.com embeds my website, thats fine, and I want the operations to go smoothly. However, if http://foreignsite.com embeds the same page, the process will not work. Is this possible?

Note: I am using iFrames for the embedding process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an [`X-Frame-Options` HTTP response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options):

```
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM http://mysite2.com
```

Comment: This is not valid anymore, this header is ignored by modern browsers. The updated approach is https://stackoverflow.com/a/77501049/6419560

Answer (score 1):

Add This On Your .htaccess file

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(First-domain\.com|Second-domain\.com)$" origin_is=$0
```

Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is

Answer (score 0):

The `X-Frame-Options` approach is not valid anymore.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options#allow-from_origin

You should be using the `Content-Security-Policy` header instead ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors#examples)). To whitelist certain domains, you can set it like this:

`Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors http://mysite1.com http://mysite2.com;`